# ms sql rounding issue in 3 to Nth decimal places

Tags: sql, sql-server, rounding

i have a problem in this query

```
select 7.115 + 2.885
```

result is 10.000

versus this query

```
select round(7.115,2) + round(2.885,2)
```

result of it is 10.010

i wonder how to make it correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is *already* correct. When you round it to 2 places, in both cases it is (correctly) being rounding *up* by effectively adding `0.005`. The sum of these two rounding deltas is `0.01` so the result being `10.01` is as expected.

There is nothing to "fix" here - it is behaving correctly and as expected.

If you mean "how do I make it display `10.00` as the result of the addition", do this:

```
select round(7.115 + 2.885, 2)
```

Comment: oh its that so...thank you so much sir to your clarification.